# JSON data as string >> MAKE object to access data?

Tags: php, post, response, json

I have a form that gets a data stream back from an outside server.  The result returns as text that **looks** like JSON, but it isn't an object - is there an easy way to turn the string below into an object so I can access the info in it?  Or am I just missing something REALLY simple?

Here's what I get back, and I need to get the `transaction_id`.  Keep in mind, this is NOT an object, just a text string.

```
{
    "result_code":     "TargetNameExist",
    "transaction_id":  "74cdb984f9914e93acbc04579d6675ee"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Json Decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function:

```
json_decode ( string $json )
```

Comment: THANKS!  I know it was simple... I was able to access the individual variable like this: 

`$jtest = json_decode ( $response->getBody(), true );
echo "transaction_id=" . $jtest['transaction_id'];`